# Javafx - image is only displayed, in last TreeItem

Tags: imageview, javafx-2

FXML code -

```
<TreeItem expanded="true" value="1"> 
    <graphic> 
        <ImageView fx:id="folderImageView"/> 
    </graphic> 
    <children> 
        <TreeItem value="11" /> 
    </children> 
</TreeItem> 

<TreeItem expanded="true" value="2"> 
    <graphic> 
        <ImageView fx:id="folderImageView"/> 
    </graphic> 
    <children> 
        <TreeItem value="2" /> 
    </children> 
</TreeItem>
```

It's controller code -

```
  public class LController implements Initializable { 

  @FXML ImageView folderImageView; 

  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) { 
      folderImageView.setImage(new Image("/resource/b.png")); 
  }
```

image b.png is only displayed, in last TreeItem (i.e. which has value=2)

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `TreeItem` should have its own `ImageView`. So the solution is to define an unique **fx:id** s for every `ImageView` in FXML. Alternatively give a fx:id="myTreeView" for `TreeView` then init both treeitems and their graphics there in controller.

Answer (score 0):

More detailed Solution on Jira - 
https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-33190

Basically below -

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
<children>
<TreeView id="tView">
<root>

<include>
<Image fx:id= "img" url="@b.png" />
</include>

<TreeItem expanded="true" value="Components">
<graphic>
<ImageView>
<image>
<fx:reference source = "img"/>
</image>
</ImageView>
</graphic>
<children>
<TreeItem value="User" />
</children>
</TreeItem>
</root>
</TreeView>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```